# Visual Studio 2013 Browser Link - Enable CTRL to Edit in Browser

Tags: visual-studio-2013, signalr, designmode, browser-link, asp.net-web-tools

How do you enable <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key for the Visual Studio **Browser Link** integration?

[Scott Hanselman discusses it here around 1:06:00](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Launch-2013/Transforming-software-development-in-a-world-of-devices-and-services) during the [VS 2013 Launch Event](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Launch-2013). I'm not sure how to activate or enable the realtime HTML Edit feature so I can edit in the browser and have the changes pushed back to Visual Studio.

Has anyone tried this out yet or can provide clues? I have VS 2013 RTM - I can't seem to find any update for ASP.NET Web Tools that may have changed this behavior. Is this an IE only behavior or is it browser independent? It sounds like it just injects additional HTML into the page.

[image: Browser Link CTRL Activation]

Comment: Adding the page inspectors runtime to to web.config might help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579399/browser-link-visual-studio-2013-not-working/37699502#37699502)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/11/05/making-web-development-wonderful-again-with-web-essentials.aspx), This appears to be a [Web Essentials 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361) extension of **Browser Link** capability. Visual Studio provides extensibility for **Browser Link** which Hanselman was sharing.

[image: Browser Link Extensions via Web Essentials]

When viewing the site, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to enable **Design Mode** which updates the Visual Studio source. Web Browser **Design Mode** for **Browser Link** is browser independent. To [enable it for non-Debug mode](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link#disabling), you need to add the following `appSettings`...

```xml
<add key="vs:enableBrowserLink" value="true" />
```