# Web Essentials Browser Link not Work in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-essentials, browser-link

I updated my project from ASP.NET MVC 4 to 5 in visual studio 2013, But now Web Essentials Browser Link not work, why? even Browser Link not show in browser!

Comment: Browser Link feature is part of visual Studio 2013. Can you try using browser link by removing web essentials from the machine?

Comment: Whats your error message? when you press CTRL+Q and type "Browser Link"

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982892/visual-studio-2013-browser-link-enable-ctrl-to-edit-in-browser) resolved my problem - the latest web.config had the value of the vs:EnableBrowserLink key set to false.

Comment: Adding the page inspectors runtime to to web.config might help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579399/browser-link-visual-studio-2013-not-working/37699502#37699502)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this (click on browser link dashboard)?

[image: click on browser link dashboard]